# REST API GetBucketCors with AWS4

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

I am trying to perform GetBucketCors operation using REST API and new AWS4 authorization. It works perfectly when I use old auth method but I cannot find out how to set canonical request right in AWS4.
I am trying to add 'cors' as first query parameter and include it into canonical request but in most of times I get error: "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
Can you suggest what should right query string should be? This is noh my canonical request looks like:

```
GET
/
cors&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJSZ2LLOUSEHIJVQQ%2F20210316%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210316T192947Z&X-Amz-Expires=10&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:<BUCKET_NAME>.s3.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have finally found it out (hint: look at amazon response more ;)
"cors" should be additional query param with "="

```
GET
/<BUCKET_NAME>/
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJSZ2LLOUSEHIJVQQ%2F20210317%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20210317T210203Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=10&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;cors=
host:s3.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
```